# How to dynamically add functions to the queue?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, queue, promise

I have `render(value)` function that I'm calling multiple times with different parameters. I need to chain calls to this function, so that it starts execution only when previous call has finished.

The function I need to chain returns a promise:

```
function render(value){
   var deferred = $q.defer();

   /* Some logic here */

   return deferred.promise;
}
```

What should I place here?

```
function onClick(value){
   /*
       Add render(value) to the queue. And start execution if queue is empty
   */
}
```

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I need dynamically add function to the queue. So that its execution only starts when all previous promises in the queue have been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just `then` chaining -

Creating the queue:

```
var queue = $q.when();
```

Adding a function to run on the queue:

```
queue = queue.then(function(){ // need to reassign since promises are immutable.
    console.log("Added!");
});
```

So, in your example:

```
function onClick(value){
  queue = queue.then(function(){ return render(value); });
}
```

Comment: Cheers, a promise basically _is_ a queue :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something along the lines of:

```
var lastPromise;

function onClick(value) {
    var promise;

    if( lastPromise ) {
        promise = lastPromise.then(function() {
            return render(value);
        }).then(cleanup);
    }
    else {
        promise = render(value).then(cleanup);
    }

    lastPromise = promise;

    function cleanup() {
        if( promise === lastPromise ) {
            lastPromise = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The `lastPromise` keeps the last promise for chaining; this makes sure that each `render()` will run after the previous has finished. The internal `promise` is a notion of the "private" promise. If, when we are resolved, the private promise is the same as the last promise, then we clean it up. WARNING: untested!

Answer (score 0):

People searching for vanila javascript solution for queing function and run can do it as following

```
//Create function to return a promise
const waitForMe = (message) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(message);
    }, 2000);
  });
};

//define promise que
let queue = Promise.resolve();
//create function to que calls to waitFroMe from callers
const QueFunction = (message) => {
  queue = queue.then(async () => {
    console.log(await waitForMe(message));
  });
};

//call QuetFunction and watch each return promise after 2000 ms (2sec)
QueFunction("Promise 1");
QueFunction("Promise 2");

//or call from button click each click will be qued and executed
const btn = document.getElementById("btn_run");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  QueFunction("Call from button click");
});
```